# Upload Facebook image URL to Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload the users facebook profile picture to Firebase Storage.

```
let dictionary = result as? NSDictionary
let data = dictionary?.objectForKey("data")
let urlPic = (data?.objectForKey("url"))! as! String
print(urlPic) //Direct link to facebook profile picture
print("Down Casting to a string")
print("\(urlPic)")
```

The code above gives me the url to the facebook picture. So that is all working fine!

However, once I have the link(URL) to the image how would I go about uploading it to Firebase Storage?

Comment: Why not just store the profile pic URL in the Firebase Realtime Database and access it from your app? There's no reason to upload it again (unless you want to edit it, etc.).

Comment: @MikeMcDonald thats a good idea because that way I won't need to waste my storage and can piggy back off facebook. I will do that thanks

Comment: this is actually a bad idea. Facebook image URLs are not permanent, they  can change, and if they do, you will not be able to retrieve the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to send a url to the storage. it will only work on the emulator, but obviously it doesn't work on a device. so you need to send the data. Check out this link. I am not fluent in swift but i made it work in the objc version so just copy and paste and troubleshoot https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/storage/StorageExampleSwift/ViewController.swift