# Get Facebook profile picture from URL

Tags: swift, url

I want to upload the profile picture from Facebook to Firebase. I tried this answer: [Upload Facebook image URL to Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007364/upload-facebook-image-url-to-firebase-storage) 
However, Swift is giving me errors on the third line of code of that answer. The code is:

```
let dictionary = result as? NSDictionary
let data = dictionary?.object(forKey: "data")
let urlPic = (data?.objectForKey("url"))! as! String
```

Swift is telling me: Cannot call value of non-function type 'Any?!' after I changed the code to what Swift keeps suggesting me:

```
let urlPic = ((data as AnyObject).object(ForKey: "url"))! as! String
```

What is the code to use when I want to retrieve the profile picture from Facebook? My goal is to also store it into Firebase, but that will come after I get the profile picture first.

Comment: Are you working with Swift 3?

Comment: You need to call the graph API. What are you using to log the user in to Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in **Swift 1.2**

I took reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333951/getting-profile-picture-with-swift-through-facebook-graph-api-return-unsupporte) and implemented also

You can do this:

```
    // accessToken is your Facebook id
func returnUserProfileImage(accessToken: NSString)
{
    var userID = accessToken as NSString
    var facebookProfileUrl = NSURL(string: "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large")

    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: facebookProfileUrl!) {
        imageProfile.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }

}
```

This is the way I got Facebook id:

```
func returnUserData()
{
let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        // Process error
        println("Error: \(error)")
    }
    else
    {
        println("fetched user: \(result)")

        if let id: NSString = result.valueForKey("id") as? NSString {
            println("ID is: \(id)")
            self.returnUserProfileImage(id)
        } else {
            println("ID es null")
        }


    }
})
}
```